# In JSTL/JSP, given a java.util.Date, how do I find the next day?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

On a JSTL/JSP page, I have a java.util.Date object from my application. I need to find the day *after* the day specified by that object. I can use <jsp:scriptlet> to drop into Java and use java.util.Calendar to do the necessary calculations, but this feels clumsy and inelegant to me.

Is there some way to use JSP or JSTL tags to achieve this end without having to switch into full-on Java, or is the latter the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a fan of putting java code in your jsp.

I'd use a static method and a taglib to accomplish this.

Just my idea though. There are many ways to solve this problem.

```
public static Date addDay(Date date){
   //TODO you may want to check for a null date and handle it.
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime (date);
   cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 1);
   return cal.getTime();
}
```

functions.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <description>functions library</description>
  <display-name>functions</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>xfn</short-name>
  <uri>http://yourdomain/functions.tld</uri>
  <function>
    <description>
      Adds 1 day to a date.
    </description>
    <name>addDay</name>
    <function-class>Functions</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.util.Date addDay(java.util.Date)</function-signature>
    <example>
      ${xfn:addDay(date)}
    </example>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

Answer (score 2):

While this does not answer your initial question, you could perhaps eliminate the hassle of going through java.util.Calendar by doing this:

```
// Date d given
d.setTime(d.getTime()+86400000);
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. In locales that use Daylight Savings Time, this will give the wrong day a couple days a year, depending on the time, and it will drive you nuts trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @FrankPape You are wrong. A java.util.Date's time property is the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT. No other time zones come into it. So sirprize is correct.

Comment: @PAG Thinking about it again, I still believe this is a bad idea, but for a different reason.

I was working off the assumption that some days do not have exactly 86400 seconds because there will be days with one hour less or more. This doesn't happen in GMT with daylight savings time, so you are right -- thanks for the correction. My new concern is leap seconds. java.util.Date does not account for leap seconds, but it's not inconceivable that some library would.

Comment: You can't object to it on the grounds that it might not work with an arbitrary library. We're discussing java.util.Date here, and that's how it works: it ignores leap seconds and defines all days to be 86400 seconds long. The code above is a simple way to progress to the next day without the Calendar round trip.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either use a scriptlet or write your own tag.  For the record, using Calendar would look like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime (date);
cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 1);
date = cal.getTime ();
```

Truly horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no tag in the standard JSP/JSTL libraries that I know of that would allow you to do this date calculation.

The simplest, and most inelegant, solution is to just use some scriptlet code to do the calculation.  You've already stated that you think this is a clunky solution, and I agree with you.  I would probably write a custom JSP taglib to get this if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think JSPs should not have data logic. They should get all the data they need to display from the Controller and all their logic should be about HOW the data is displayed, not WHAT is displayed. This is usually a lot simpler and a lot less code/XML than adding a custom tag.

And if there isn't any re-use happening, is a tiny scriptlet really that much worse than the taglib XML?