# converting strings to Title case in JSTL

Tags: java, string, jstl

Is there any way to convert a string to Title case, using JSTL tags?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Great question, and yet another short-coming of JSTL. Title case is a very basic display need. These answers are all good and valid, but I find it insulting that the creators of JSTL failed to include this functionality directly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An alternative to transforming the string on the server is to [let CSS do the work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#caps-prop):

```
text-transform: capitalize
```

Comment: cool. It helped, since I needed the Title Case only for presentation purpose, CSS would be a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why always looking for complex answer? Your solution is really the best one!

Comment: In a way, this isn't a very good answer to "how can I do it in JSTL". I like romaintaz's explanation, since it better covers how someone could do it in JSTL.

Comment: @Nick - I think that's a fair comment but it does no harm to read between the lines occasionally and suggest alternatives.

Comment: This only works with certain inputs with CSS.  For example if my input Data is ALL UPPERCASE, capitalize will not work, it will leave my text as is in it's uppercase format.  EX: someone enters last name in all caps.  I want to display this name with proper/title case, then no go using CSS, the name will be displayed all caps.

Comment: This one works for all upper case too.

.m_name{
text-transform:lowercase;
}
.m_name:first-letter{
text-transform:uppercase;
}

Answer (score 8):

An idea:

In a class, create a simple method that uses the WordUtils from Apache Commons Lang that will manipulate your String:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;

...

public static String titleCase(String input){
   return WordUtils.capitalize(input);;
}
```

And now, create your own tag (in a function.tld) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <description>functions library</description>
  <display-name>functions</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>xfn</short-name>
  <uri>http://yourdomain/functions.tld</uri>
  <function>
    <description>
      Title case a String
    </description>
    <name>titleCase</name>
    <function-class>Functions</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String titleCase(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    <example>
      ${xfn:titleCase(string)}
    </example>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

ps: I was quite inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248/in-jstl-jsp-given-a-java-util-date-how-do-i-find-the-next-day) to give my answer.

Comment: He's looking for Title Case not all uppercase

Comment: The capitalize() method does not transform your String in uppercase ! Eventually do StringUtils.capitalize(StringUtils.lowerCase(theString)) !

Comment: Maybe it wasn't available at the time of answering, but you could also use capitalizeFully in WordUtils. It handles words that are already all caps.

Answer (score 8):

It's not too super hard in JSTL...

```
${fn:toUpperCase(fn:substring(user.firstName, 0, 1))}${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substring(user.firstName, 1, -1))}
```

Comment: This fails when the middle initial is included in the first name. It ends up lower case.