# I need to convert string in JSP into titlecase

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

I have a variable in JSP tag file as below

```
<span class="breadcrumbName">${breadcrumb.name}</span>
```

I need to convert the text/string from this variable into Title Case ... Can someone please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the following

```
${fn:toUpperCase(fn:substring(breadcrumb.name, 0, 1))}${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substring(breadcrumb.name, 1, -1))}
```

make sure you have the following

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Comment: Does this not give you sentence case, as opposed to title case?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sentence case :( .. any help on how to make it title case? A jstl approach will be nice

Answer (score -2):

I dont think so you can convert the string's case in el, I may be wrong

You can use css to find a workaround by applying proper styling to your span tag

```
<span style="text-transform: capitalize;"
 class="breadcrumbName">${breadcrumb.name}</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will only make it capitalize.. I need title case. So if breadcrumb text is "my life". I want "My Life" and not "My life"

Comment: Finally Solved it as follows

<fmt:message key="some.key" var="breadcrumb.name"/>

${fn:toLowerCase(breadcrumb.name)}

Using css turn the text to capitalize..

Comment: If you don't want to rely on CSS, you could always do as per this answer — http://stackoverflow.com/a/482959/1474421 & use WordUtils in a custom taglib.