# Java Generate all dates between x and y

Tags: java, date-range

I attempted to generate the date range between date x and date y but failed. I have the same method in c# so I tried to modify it as much as I can but failed to get result. Any idea what I could fix?

```
private ArrayList<Date> GetDateRange(Date start, Date end) {
    if(start.before(end)) {
        return null;
    }

    int MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    ArrayList<Date> listTemp = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date tmpDate = start;

    do {
        listTemp.add(tmpDate);
        tmpDate = tmpDate.getTime() + MILLIS_IN_DAY;
    } while (tmpDate.before(end) || tmpDate.equals(end));

    return listTemp;
}
```

To be honest I was trying to get all the dates starting from january 1st till the end of year 2012 that is december 31st. If any better way available, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Joda-Time

Calendar and Date APIs in java are really weird... I strongly suggest to consider jodatime, which is the de-facto library to handle dates.
It is really powerful, as you can see from the quickstart: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html.

This code solves the problem by using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class DateQuestion {

    public static List<DateTime> getDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {

        List<DateTime> ret = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
        DateTime tmp = start;
        while(tmp.isBefore(end) || tmp.equals(end)) {
            ret.add(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.plusDays(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime start = DateTime.parse("2012-1-1");
        System.out.println("Start: " + start);

        DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2012-12-31");
        System.out.println("End: " + end);

        List<DateTime> between = getDateRange(start, end);
        for (DateTime d : between) {
            System.out.println(" " + d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just messing with the code above, I kinda agree with ur view. I never used calendar before but it is not so nice.

Comment: This is really coooool sooooo thanks verrrrrry much ;)

Comment: FYI, the *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode. It’s main creator, Stephen Colebourne, went on to found and lead the JSR 310 project, implemented as the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
Year year = Year.of ( 2012 ) ;  // Represent an entire year.

year
.atDay( 1 )                     // Determine the first day of the year. Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.datesUntil(                    // Generates a `Stream<LocalDate>`.
    year
    .plusYears( 1 )             // Returns a new `Year` object, leaving the original unaltered. 
    .atDay( 1 )                 // Returns a `LocalDate`.
)                               // Returns a `Stream<LocalDate>`.
.forEach(                       // Like a `for` loop, running through each object in the stream.
    System.out :: println       // Each `LocalDate` object in stream is passed to a call of `System.out.println`.
)
;
```

## java.time

The other Answers are outmoded as of Java 8.

The old date-time classes bundled with earlier versions of Java have been supplanted with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate` (date-only)

If you care only about the date without the time-of-day, use the `LocalDate` class. The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

To get the current date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, today’s date varies by time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

We can use the `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods to compare. In date-time work we commonly use the Half-Open approach where the beginning of a span of time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
List<LocalDate> localDates = new ArrayList<>();
LocalDate localDate = start;
while ( localDate.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    localDates.add( localDate );
    // Set up the next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

#### `LocalDate::datesUntil`

You can obtain a stream of `LocalDate` objects.

```
Stream< LocalDate > dates = start.datesUntil( stop ) ;
dates.forEach( System.out::println ) ;
```

#### `LocalDateRange`

If doing much of this work, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. This gives you the `LocalDateRange` class to represent your pair of start and stop `LocalDate` objects.

### `Instant` (date-time)

If you have old java.util.Date objects, which represent both a date and a time, convert to the `Instant` class. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant startInstant = juDate_Start.toInstant();
Instant stopInstant = juDate_Stop.toInstant();
```

From those `Instant` objects, get `LocalDate` objects by:

- Applying the time zone that makes sense for your context to get `ZonedDateTime` object. This object is the very same moment on the timeline as the `Instant` but with a specific time zone assigned.
- Convert the `ZonedDateTime` to a `LocalDate`.

We must apply a time zone as a date only has meaning within the context of a time zone. As we said above, for any given moment the date varies around the world.

Example code.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate start = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( startInstant , zoneId ).toLocalDate();
LocalDate stop = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( stopInstant , zoneId ).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: I think the while condition should be `while(localDate.isBefore( stop ))`, as the `start` variable is not updated.

Comment: @LeonidasK Fixed. Thanks. FYI, on Stack Overflow, you are welcome to edit an Answer yourself to fix such issues.

Answer (score 7):

You could use this function:

```
public static Date addDay(Date date){
   //TODO you may want to check for a null date and handle it.
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime (date);
   cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 1);
   return cal.getTime();
}
```

[Found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248/in-jstl-jsp-given-a-java-util-date-how-do-i-find-the-next-day)
And what is the reason of fail? Why you think that your code is failed?

Comment: it fails on one line  tmpDate = tmpDate.getTime() + MILLIS_IN_DAY);
because getTime() isn't there :) But thanks will try ur code then output to the list :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

```
Days.daysBetween(fromDate, toDate);
```

Found at joda-time homepage.

[similar question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838527/android-java-date-difference-in-days) with some good answers.

Comment: yeah, joda time rules! (and you "stole" my answer ;-) )

Comment: sry ... didnt see your post before I was hitting the send button ;)

Comment: the next time I have to write faster... I saw a new answer just when I finish writing my own one! :-)

Comment: Haha guys its cool even duplicate answers are useful. Will use joda for sure..but hope I could still use the standard methods of date

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API, particularly Calendar.add().