# How to capture the random dates between specific limit in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

In my application, DOB field having limit of specific interval. I want to capture random dates between 1-Jan-1950 to 31-Dec-2000. please suggest. thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Beanshell preprocessor to get a Random DOB.
Just copy & paste the below code. It should work.

I am storing the random date in the 'dob' variable. So, just use ${dob} in the date of birth field.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

int randBetween(int start, int end) {
        return start + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
    }

gc = new GregorianCalendar();
year = randBetween(1950, 2000);
gc.set(gc.YEAR, year);
dayOfYear = randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR));
gc.set(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);  
vars.put("dob", (dateFormat2.format(dateFormat1.parse(gc.get(gc.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (gc.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + gc.get(Calendar.YEAR)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bean shell script sampler** to call java apis and using  Joda time - java library you can generate the dates between two specific dates as shown below( Ref: [Java Generate all dates between x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166390/java-generate-all-dates-between-x-and-y)) and pick list item dates in random wise,
Refer [this link for using  Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) in jmeter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class DateQuestion {

    public static List<DateTime> getDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {

        List<DateTime> ret = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
        DateTime tmp = start;
        while(tmp.isBefore(end) || tmp.equals(end)) {
            ret.add(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.plusDays(1);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime start = DateTime.parse("2012-1-1");
        System.out.println("Start: " + start);

        DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2012-12-31");
        System.out.println("End: " + end);

        List<DateTime> between = getDateRange(start, end);
        for (DateTime d : between) {
            System.out.println(" " + d);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me know how to use it in jmeter, please tell me some steps