# how to import joda time in java on Ubuntu system

Tags: java, date, ubuntu, import, jodatime

I'd like to generate dates sequence in a range. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166390/java-generate-all-dates-between-x-and-y) thread suggests to use Joda-Time package. I downloaded [it](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases) and unzipped it to the same directory as my Main.java.

When I try `import ./joda-time-2.7/org.joda.time.DateTime;`, the compiler says:

> Main.java:4: error:  expected
>
> import ./joda-time-2.7/org.joda.time.DateTime;
>
> ```
>  ^
> ```
>
> Main.java:4: error:  expected
>
> import ./joda-time-2.7/org.joda.time.DateTime;
>
> ```
>   ^
> ```
>
> Main.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>
> import ./joda-time-2.7/org.joda.time.DateTime;
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```

And when I try `import org.joda.time.DateTime;`, the compiler says:

> MissingDateSearch.java:5: error: package org.joda.time does not exist
>
> import org.joda.time.DateTime;
>
> ```
>               ^
> ```

It seems that I didn't include the package into my building path. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=217936&highlight=classpath) thread discusses how to set the building path for java. Currently, my "environment" file only has PATH variable. I don't want to make any global change just for one project.

So my question is, does any one know how to include the package in a way without global change? Or does any one has a simple way to generate dates in a range without joda-time?

Thanks!

ADDED

This problem can be bypassed by using IDEs like eclipse. Any terminal based solutions are still welcomed.

Comment: you need to include the jar file in your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

import statement and ensure that JodaTime jar file is on your classpath at compile & runtime

Comment: Thanks! However, when I try `javac Main.java -classpath ./joda-time-2.7/
`, it says "error: package org.joda.time does not exist".

Comment: you need to add the JAR file to your compile classpath, e.g. `javac -cp .:joda-time-1.6.2.jar Main.java`

Comment: When I try `javac Main.java -cp ./joda-time-2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar`, it compiles fine. However, when I run the program, it has "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant". I run the same code as the accepted answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166390/java-generate-all-dates-between-x-and-y).

Comment: Use the same classpath when running the application

Comment: Thanks for your instruction, but `java Main -cp ./joda-time-2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar` still results in the same exception as `java Main`.

Comment: You're missing the current directory from the classpath as I have shown above

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly. I used `javac Main.java -cp ./joda-time-2.7/joda-time.2.7.jar` since the jar file is under the "joda-time-2.7" directory and has the same name. This complies fine. When I run the program using `java Main -cp ./joda-time-2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar`, it has the above exception, which is the same exception when I run the program using `java Main`. I do not understand the symbol ".:" in your first answer, but I think I've already included in the class path by the -cp option. But I still get the exception.